# Tryed to make an Auto Like Bot for Instagram

Tags: javascript, bots

```js
var postList = document.getElementsByClassName("eLAPa");
var likeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9");

var counter = 0;

let sleep (ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

async function like() {;

    postList[counter].click();

    await sleep(1000);

    likeButton[1].click();

    await sleep(1000);

    document.querySelector('.ckWGn').click();

    await sleep(1000);

    counter++;
    like();

}

like();
```

I am a complete noob in this but i tried to make an Bot which Likes posts from a Instagram Feed.
I always get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

Comment: it can’t be `let sleep (ms) =>`. You have to add an equals sign (=) like this: `let sleep = ms =>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot an equals sign, as @MrMythical pointed out. You also shouldn't have a semicolon after `async function like() {`. Try this code and let me know if it works!

```js
var postList = document.getElementsByClassName("eLAPa");
var likeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9");

var counter = 0;

let sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

async function like() {

    postList[counter].click();

    await sleep(1000);

    likeButton[1].click();

    await sleep(1000);

    document.querySelector('.ckWGn').click();

    await sleep(1000);

    counter++;
    like();

}

like();
```